# How to insert and update multiple selected values with codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

So I have a problem with many to many relationships. 
Currently, I have `surat` and `surat_user` table.
How do I insert data into `surat` and at the same time insert multiple values from `select2` multiple forms into `surat_user` table and how to get data so I can update it.

**UPDATE** : 
I solve the insert problem please see answer below

But now i have no idea **how to update those values**.
For example

`surat_user`

```
id_surat | id_user
    1    |  1
    1    |  2
```

How to update `surat_user` (in controller and model) if i want to remove one of `id_user` where 'id_surat =  1`

At the moment i don't know how to fetch the multiple values into select2 form edit so here is mu uncomplete codes :

Controller

```
public function edit_sm($id_surat){
    $this->load->view('template/header');       
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
    $where = array('id_surat' => $id_surat);
    //$data=array('id_status'=> $this->M_sm->get_option()); 
    $data['surat'] = $this->M_sm->edit_sm($where,'surat')->result();
    $this->load->view('v_edit_surat',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}

public function edit_sm_proses() {
    $data = array(
        'id_surat'=>$this->input->post('id_surat'),
        'no_surat'=>$this->input->post('no_surat'),
        'id_status'=>$this->input->post('id_status'),
        'id_user'=>$this->input->post('id_user')
        );
    $where = array(
    'id_surat' => $id_surat
);

    $this->M_sm->edit_sm_proses($where,$data,'surat');
    redirect('SuratMasuk');
}
```

Model:

```
public function edit_sm($where,$table){     
    $this->db->join('status_surat', 'status_surat.id_status = surat.id_status');
    return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
}

public function edit_sm_proses($where,$data,$table){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($table,$data);
}
```

View

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-solid box-primary"">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Default Box Example</h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body">
            <?php foreach ($surat as $key) { ?>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()."SuratMasuk/edit_sm_proses" ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id_surat" value="<?=$key->id_surat?>">


        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-2">No Surat</label>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" name="no_surat" class="form-control no_surat" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor Surat" value="<?=$key->no_surat?>">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Status</label>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <select class="form-control select2 id_status" name="id_status" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="<?=$key->id_status;?>" selected="<?=$key->id_status;?>"><?php echo $key->status;?></option>
                <?php foreach ($id_status as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->id_status; ?>"> <?php echo $row->status; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
                </select>
           <span class="help-block"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Disposisi</label>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <select class="form-control select2 id_user" name="id_user[]" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="<?=$key->id_user;?>" selected="<?=$key->id_user;?>"><?php echo $key->nama;?></option>
                <?php foreach ($id_user as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->id_user; ?>"> <?php echo $row->nama; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
                </select>
           <span class="help-block"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer">
           <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
           <button class="btn btn-info">Update</button><br>
           <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>SuratMasuk/">Kembali</a>
          </form>
           <?php  
                }
                ?>
          </div>
          <!-- box-footer -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Current Result :
[result from codes above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FYm4.jpg)

Comment: i manage to solve insert multiple values by myself, but now I'm having problem how to update those values. I don't know what to do to fetch values from `surat_user`. For example i have `id surat = 1 and it has `id_user = 1` and `id user = 2`. What i have to do if i want to update `id surat = 1` and make it only has one `id_user`

Comment: First, Don't use `<form>` inside the `foreach` loop. Use eidt/update button for each record

Comment: if i don't use form inside `foreach` then how am i supposed to get the data from database and show it to form edit ?

Comment: when you click on button function will call with an ID then data will get from DB.

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?=  base_url('controller_name/function_name/'. $id)?>">Edit</a>`

Comment: yes i already use that, the code im showing above is a view for edit form. while the edit button is at other view. as you can see in the image i put in current result, you can see the url+id. i got that url from the code i write on edit button.

Comment: i wrote this in edit button `<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>SuratMasuk/edit_sm/.\<?=$row->id_surat;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a>`

Comment: Have you got the record from DB to edit?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SuratMasuk extends CI_Controller {
    public function add_sm_proses(){
    $data = array(
                'no_surat'=>$this->input->post('no_surat'),
                'id_status'=>$this->input->post('id_status'),   
        );
```

Select **MAX ID** from table like this

```
    $id_surat = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(surat.id_surat) AS maxid FROM surat')->row()->maxid;
```

**Update:-**
`$id_surat` will give **MAX ID** present in the table. Don't use for next record.
First, Increment it by value 1 and then use it

```
$id_surat = $id_surat + 1;
$id_user = $this->input->post('id_user') ? $this->input->post('id_user') : array();
```

First, check if `$id_user` have values or not otherwise foreach loop will give e error

```
    if(count($id_user) > 0){
        foreach ($id_user as $u){
            $data_values = array('id_surat' => $id_surat, 'id_user' => $u);
            $this->db->insert('surat_user', $data_values);
        }
    }
    $insert = $this->M_sm->add_sm($data);
```

`$insert` will not always return `1`. So, only check if value exists

```
    if($insert){
            redirect('SuratMasuk');
        }   else {
            echo "<h2>Gagal menambahkan data</h2>";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've solve the insert problem , but now i don't know how to update those values. i edited my post, can you help me,please?

Comment: ah what i mean is `id surat =  1` has multiple values then i want to update it and remove one of the values in `surat_user` but when i tried to update the `surat_user` table become duplicated values because instead of removing `id_user = 1` it changes`id_user =  1` into `id_user = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the problem by my self.

i change my **controller** to this:

```
public function add_sm_proses(){
    $data = array(
        'no_surat'=>$this->input->post('no_surat'),
        'id_status'=>$this->input->post('id_status')    
    );
    $insert = $this->M_sm->trans_surat_user($data);
    if($insert=1){
        redirect('SuratMasuk');
    }   else {
        echo "<h2>Gagal menambahkan data</h2>";

    }
}
```

change my **model** to this :

```
public function trans_surat_user($data){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('surat', $data);
    $id_surat = $this->db->query('SELECT surat.id_surat FROM surat ORDER BY id_surat DESC limit 1');
    foreach ($id_surat->result() as $row) {
        $id_surat_result = $row->id_surat;
    }
    $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
    foreach ($id_user as $data2) {
        array_push($id_user, $data2);
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO surat_user (id_surat,id_user) VALUES ('.$id_surat_result.','.$data2.')');

    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Show all record from DB and for each record add a button to edit the record.

**Note:-** Don't use `<form>` inside the loop

```
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="<?= base_url('SuratMasuk/edit_sm/'.$row->id_surat)?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</a>
```

**Controller for Edit**

I'm just adding backend code here

> **where** and **table** is reserved word for DB. It is better to not use it or use in another way.

```
public function edit_sm($id_surat){ 
    $condition_array = array('id_surat' => $id_surat);
    $data['surat'] = $this->M_sm->edit_sm($condition_array ,'surat');
}
```

**Model for Edit**

Get the record for edit

This function is getting only one record from DB so use `row()`

```
public function edit_sm($condition_array ,$record_in){     
    $this->db->join('status_surat', 'status_surat.id_status = surat.id_status');
    return $this->db->get_where($record_in, $condition_array )->row();
}
```

Now, Form for will show with data populated in it.

Getting updated data from Controller

```
public function edit_sm_proses() {
    $data = array(
        'id_surat'=> $this->input->post('id_surat'),
        'no_surat'=>$this->input->post('no_surat'),
        'id_status'=>$this->input->post('id_status'),
        'id_user'=>$this->input->post('id_user')
        );
    $condition_array = array(
    'id_surat' => $this->input->post('id_surat')
);

    $this->M_sm->edit_sm_proses($condition_array, $data, 'surat');
    redirect('SuratMasuk');
}
```

Updating data in Model

```
public function edit_sm_proses($condition_array, $data, $record_in){
    $this->db->where($condition_array);
    return $this->db->update($record_in, $data);
}
```